# Mysql connect = No database selected? then Access denied

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a php mysql connect script.
I wanted it to use functions so I can keep a track what is what, so Mysql connect got one function.
When I run it, I get first "No database selected" and when I specify it manually, it says "Access denied for @ localhost".

Code

```
<?php
/* Mysql Data */
$MySqlUser = "root";
$MySqlPass = "**********";
$MySqlHost = "localhost";
$MySqlDataBase = "serveradmin";
/* End Mysql Data */
function MySqlConnect() {
    $Connect = mysql_connect($MySqlHost, $MySqlUser, $MySqlPass);
    $Database = mysql_select_db($MySqlDataBase);
    if (!$Connect | !$Database) {
        die("Cannot connect ".mysql_error());
    }
}
MySqlConnect()
?>
```

So the problem, what causes this? I want the script to be nice and clean, and not sure if function() causes it.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: It's also not clear what you are trying to achieve with that function since the database handle is never returned.

Comment: u need to pass the arguments to the function, right no it isn;t taking any args

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fix it, but please look into [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

```
<?php
/* Mysql Data */
$MySqlUser = "root";
$MySqlPass = "**********";
$MySqlHost = "localhost";
$MySqlDataBase = "serveradmin";
/* End Mysql Data */
function MySqlConnect($MySqlUser, $MySqlPass, $MySqlHost, $MySqlDataBase ) {
    $Connect = mysql_connect($MySqlHost, $MySqlUser, $MySqlPass);
    $Database = mysql_select_db($MySqlDataBase);
    if (!$Connect | !$Database) {
        die("Cannot connect ".mysql_error());
    }
    return $Database;
}
$Database = MySqlConnect($MySqlUser, $MySqlPass, $MySqlHost, $MySqlDataBase );
?>
```